# how to round really long decimals

Tags: php, math, rounding

Is there any way in PHP to round this decimal? i've tried `round()`

```
$dec = 5    
$df=(100*($dec/100))/99999;
```

output: 5.0000500005E-5

I need to make it 5,00 or 5,01 just to make it round.

I'm not good in PHP but i think that problem is in that E-5

Comment: Have you tried round()'s second parameter, which specifies the number of decimal digits to round to?

Comment: Well then your question is not clear. What is your input to round(), and what is the output? In your example you're just doing some manual maths.

Comment: 5.0000500005E-5 is output even with E-5

Comment: seeing all your `Tried and didn't helped` seems that you want a custom `round`, for which you didn't give enough specs

Comment: I asked what your input to the round() function was. You've told us the output. Really struggling to help here...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a 2nd parameter for length of the precision:

```
float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )
```

For example"

```
echo round(1.2354636456, 2);
```

Output is:

```
1.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Use round(). Simply You are trying to divide 5 by 9999 which is equal to 0.00050005. Here if you set the precison to 2 you will get 0. Set 4 you will get 0.0001

```
 echo(round(0.00050005,4));
```

Here 4 is called precision. The number of decimal digits to round to

Comment: Tried and didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

I've had problem in PhP version round wasn't working cause of some bug in installation script works on other server